# Setting id in android layout fails

Tags: android

I would like to set an id to my layout programmatically but it always shows an error even thoug it executes just fine,
How do i end the error displayed in the code:

```
RelativeLayout newlayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        newlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        newlayout.setId(int 12);
```

The execution is okay but my code always shows an error
[image]

Comment: if you cast the int in the line above, it still shows the error?

Comment: Yes still shows

Comment: which error is shown? I mean the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a res folder for ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
            <item type="id" name="id1" />
            <item type="id" name="id2" />
            <item type="id" name="id3" />
    </resources>
```

Then add that resource ID to the setID() method:

```
newLayout.setId(R.id.id1);
```

Comment: Also please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665406/setting-stacked-up-layout-programmatically-in-android